# Gridview dropdownlist must show item in dataset as its selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html.dropdownlistfor

i have a dropdownlist in a column in a gridview. This dropdwon already had two items in it i.e Close/Open. What i require is that I bind the gridview to a dataset, all i want is for the dropdown to show the value that is in the dataset.(open or close)

Comment: show some code what u tried??

Comment: good luck with that, let us know how u get on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Its a bit of an work around. You cannot directly bind the gridview dropdownlist to the dataset column. What I did instead was, I bound the Dataset column to a hiddenfield and then in Rowdatabound event i assigned the dropdown.selectedvalue to the hiddenfield.value.

Works Perfectly...Thanks everyone.